# How to squeeze and stretch a pipe? Organ (intestine) animation

Tags: animation

I'm doing my assignment which I have to create an animation of organ(intestine)'s digestion.
I have to make organ (let's call it 'pipe' from now on) interact with excrement inside of itself.

[image]

The pipe should be squeezed(tightened?) a little bit before and after excrement passes the pipe, and as the excrement passes the pipe, that part should stretch(bulge?).
bowel movement? peristalsis? don't know the exact term...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ujr0UAbyPS4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CoIDScAzog

links above are ideal animation I want as a result...

I'm a real beginner, and I learned basic modeling, sculpting and rigging tutorials.
But I have no idea how to do this.
Should I use IK rig? or soft body collision..?
I don't ask for full solution. I just want to know the direction.
I't would be great if there're some tutorials how to use those tools...

Help plz...

Comment: I proposed the Cast modifier here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123276/messed-up-intestine-animation-with-lattice-modifier  if you give it a vertex group it will work fine and easy