# Stretch object over surface if objects intersect

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I am attempting to make an animation where one object passes through another hollow object, with the hollow object stretching to accommodate the moving object. The problem I'm having however is how to achieve this in a way where the hollow object will only deform where the moving object would be bigger than the hollow object, but otherwise stay the same. An example would be like a snake eating something - it stays it's normal size everywhere except where the mouse or whatever is. I've looked at the shrink-wrap modifier but I can't get it to only affect intersecting vertices and such. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Here you have 2 solutions, Lattice or Cast modifiers, is it what you want? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123276/messed-up-intestine-animation-with-lattice-modifier

Comment: Lattice looks the most promising, though I'm not sure exactly to get it to behave the way I'd like - essentially I'm making an animation where a character puts a wrestling style mask on and I just want it to stretch over the main part of the head where the neck hole and lower part of the mask are too small, but the face section isn't affected. I can almost get it to work though it seems a bit tricky to get it to affect the right part, I don't think I fully comprehend how the lattice should be set up for my situation since the mask and my character's head are the same size once it's fully worn.

Comment: maybe show 2 pictures of storyboard, it would help. Yes Lattice seems the way to go. You also have the Mesh Deform modifier, it's close to the Lattice but doesn't work exactly the same. You could also directly work with Shpekeys. Edit: not easy if you want to show the shape of the face (like nose) stretch the mask object though... Shrinkwrap should be the tool but it doesn't seem to work fine...

Comment: here is something (Vertex Weight Proximity + Displace modifiers) that would work with a non deformed surface: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin/153179#153179  but combined with a lattice, it seems hard.