# How can I stretch a soft body like a real jelly?

Tags: soft-body

I want to stretch a soft body like a real jelly.

I made cubes into the jelly and hooked to empty axes.

When I moved the axes to a different direction, the soft body stretched like this:

Picture:

[image]

But I want to stretch the cube like this:

Picture:

[image]

Is this possible in Blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124595/how-to-make-an-open-object-behave-like-rubber-when-penetrated-by-another

Comment: For such soft body distortion on stretching you’d need to add internal structure to your mesh. With real-world materials it’s the pulling of those internal bonds that pulls together the opposite outer surfaces.

Answer (score 4):

You could try it with *Cloth* simulation: Hook each extremity to 2 empties (or bones), make each extremity part of the same group that you call *Pin*, give your object a *Cloth* simulation / *Rubber* and choose the group called *Pin* as *Shape > Pin Group*. Make sure that the *Cloth* modifier is under the 2 *Hook* modifiers. It probably needs some tweakings (you could also cheat a bit with some shape keys):

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: could you upload that blender file? I will follow what you did ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer to share the file. I've used the Rubber settings and tweaked the Stiffness values a bit